# Bluetoothctl or gatttool for BLE notifications from multiple devices

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I have read many questions on the topic but found no information on how to best (or if it is even possible) to receive notifications from more than 1 device at a time using any library or API (preferably command line or Python library).

After connecting to different devices e.g. Heart Rate monitor and Phone, or two HR monitors, is there a way to receive data from 1 service from each device at the same time?

**EDIT:**

I have managed to connect different devices of the same characteristics and been able to get notifications from them using Bluetoothctl (part of Bluez) so long as I don't request the same service, which answers my question partially; still, does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you show your code that is not working? All libs I have seen are device/connection-based (one object per device/connection) so it shouldn't matter if you have 1 or 10 devices.

Comment: I am trying to do it using the bluetoothctl commands at first, so using "scan on" and "connect <MAC addr.>" then selecting a service and listening for notifications. This does not allow two devices to send data using the same service, so I thought maybe there is some API that allows for this, provided the hardware can handle it.

Comment: bluetoothctl is a user-interactive debug tool, not an API nor a library. As long as you write a program with a real API you will get the functionality you want.

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying different ones to see which works best.

Answer (score 6):

1) First of all there is a github python project that does just that in Linux on Raspberry Pi: https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy

2) Second this [snipet from Anthony Chiu](https://anthonychiu.xyz/2016/04/05/communication-between-raspberry-pi-and-multiple-arduinos-via-bluetooth-low-power-ble/)  uses that API to communicate with multiple devices using notifications:

```
  from bluepy.btle import Scanner, DefaultDelegate, Peripheral
    import threading

    class NotificationDelegate(DefaultDelegate):

    def __init__(self, number):
        DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)
        self.number = number

    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        print 'Notification:\nConnection:'+str(self.number)+ \nHandler:'+str(cHandle)+'\nMsg:'+data

    bt_addrs = ['00:15:83:00:45:98', '00:15:83:00:86:72']
    connections = []
    connection_threads = []
    scanner = Scanner(0)

    class ConnectionHandlerThread (threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, connection_index):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.connection_index = connection_index

        def run(self):
            connection = connections[self.connection_index]
            connection.setDelegate(NotificationDelegate(self.connection_index))
            while True:
                if connection.waitForNotifications(1):
                    connection.writeCharacteristic(37, 'Thank you for the notification!')

    while True:
        print'Connected: '+str(len(connection_threads))
        print 'Scanning...'
        devices = scanner.scan(2)
        for d in devices:
            print(d.addr)
            if d.addr in bt_addrs:
                p = Peripheral(d)
                connections.append(p)
                t = ConnectionHandlerThread(len(connections)-1)
                t.start()
                connection_threads.append(t)
```

3) I will just write the manual connection option with bluetoothctl that you probably tried. Since it wasn't listed here, I will add that too:

**Manual connection with bluetoothctl: ** To get the list of characteristics you can use the “list-attributes” command after establing connection and entering *Generic Attribute Submenu* through `menu gatt` in bluetoothctl, which should print the same list as above:

```
list-attributes 00:61:61:15:8D:60
```

To read an attribute you first select it, with the -you guessed it- “select-attribute” command:

```
select-attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_61_61_15_8D_60/service000a/char000b
```

After that you can issue the “read” command, without any parameters.

To read a characteristic continuously (if characteristic supports it) , use the “notify” command:

```
notify on
```

PS: This is my first answer on stackoverflow :) 
I am also new to BLE, so bear with me. Am interested in your project, any links / contact are appreciated :) 
You can find me on alexandrudancu.com

Comment: This was my first question on stackoverflow too. After posting this question I found this library and other similar ones, but I have since left this project aside for now. Thanks for the answer (even if a bit late).

Comment: thanks for the vote! 
come back to the bluetooth world! :)